# Crear acumulador JSTL

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

Estoy creando un pagina usando JSTL y quiero crear una variable que acumule un total dentro de dos `forEach`

```xhtml
<c:forEach var="mesas" items="${result.cuentas.mesas}">
  <c:forEach var="saldoMesa" items="${mesas.saldo}">
    Aqui quiero que mi variable se acumule
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Ese es mi código, y quiero imprimir dicha variable en un div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `<c:set>`:

```xhtml
<c:set var="contador" value="${0}" />
<c:forEach var="mesas" items="${result.cuentas.mesas}">
    <c:forEach var="saldoMesa" items="${mesas.saldo}">
        <c:set var="contador" value="${contador + saldoMesa}" />
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
<div>
    Resultado: ${contador}
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, me resultó !!